# Java - Collection.Sort over Interface Objects

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparable

I have a number of abstract classes each superclassing three or four concrete ones and of the form:

```
public abstract class TypeOfMapObject extends IrrelevantClass implements Serializable, MapObject, Comparable<MapObject>
{
  //irrelevant stuff
  @Override
  public int compareTo(MapObject m)
  {
    //specific algorithm for natural ordering
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code I have an `ArrayList<MapObject>` (which is being populated correctly, I have checked that) called `tempMapObjectsArray`  I want to sort that `ArrayList` using `Collections.sort(tempMapObjectsArray)` (or, rather, I want to sort that `ArrayList` and it seems `Collections.sort()` is the best way to do it.  The specific way its sorted isn't important).

It's not compiling and giving the message (in Netbeans):

```
no suitable method found for sort(java.util.ArrayList<Model.MapObject>)
 method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
 (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
 method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>) is not applicable
  (inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
   inferred: Model.MapObject
   bound(s): java.lang.Comparable<? super Model.MapObject>)
```

It seems that I am defining the generic wrong in the `TypeOfMapObject` class, but this is the first time I have really used generics and it's reached the stage where I am simply trying things more or less at random.  I'm reading through the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) but so far it's simply not "clicking" what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Each of the subclasses of the various abstract classes need to be comparable to each other - so if I have abstract classes `TypeofMapObject1`, `TypeOfMapObject2` etc, then I need to be able to compare a subclass of 1 to a subclass of 2.

Comment: When you say "It's throwing up..." you mean that the above snippet compiles and you get the exception in runtime?

Comment: No, sorry for being unclear.  Its a compile time error.  Edited to reflect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Match the Comparable type with the class:

```
public abstract class TypeOfMapObject extends IrrelevantClass implements Serializable, MapObject, Comparable<TypeOfMapObject> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TypeOfMapObject m)
    {
        //specific algorithm for natural ordering
    }
}
```

Or simply don't define the compareTo method in your abstract class - leave it for the subclass to implement.

---

To address edit to question:

If you want to compare different subtypes, have them implement a method that returns a value (say String) with which they may be compared. For example:

```
public abstract class TypeOfMapObject extends IrrelevantClass implements Serializable, MapObject, Comparable<TypeOfMapObject> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TypeOfMapObject m)
    {
        return compareValue().compareTo(m.compareValue());
    }

    // subclasses to return their value to compare
    protected abstract String compareValue();
}
```

The type returned from the `compareValue()` can be anything compareable, eg Integer, Date, whatever.

Comment: SOrry for being unclear - I do need to be able to compare different `TypeOfMapOject` things to one another - so of the multiple types of abstract class they all need to be comparable to each other.  Edited question to reflect this.

Comment: Genius!  I got hung up on generics and didn't look at other options.  Thank you.